# how to get rdf file from jena fuseki server and initialize it to my OntModel in Apache Jena?

Tags: java, jena, fuseki

I learn that you can extract rdf file and initialize to Model in jena using this codes:

`DatasetAccessor accessor = DatasetAccessorFactory.createHTTP("http://localhost:3030/ds/data"); 
Model updated = accessor.getModel();`

but when I try to put it in OntModel like this:

```
 OntModel updated = accessor.getModel();
```

it yields an error like this: `Incompatible types: Model cannot be converted to OntModel`

And also when I try to do this: `OntModel model = (OntModel) accessor.getModel();`

it still output an error saying: `com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom cannot be cast to com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel`

Comment: thank you for the quick reply @AndyS, sorry for the incomplete question. the error is : `Incompatible types: Model cannot be converted to OntModel`

Comment: See ModelFactory which has operations for making OntModels from plain ones.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't get OntModel from Fuseki directly, however what you can do is save the Model in a local file and then read it into an OntModel. e.g.:

```
OntModel ontModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);
    DatasetAccessor myDA = DatasetAccessorFactory.createHTTP("URL");
    Model model = myDA.getModel("GRAPH");

File myFile = new File(_path);
        try
        {
            PrintStream ps_Writer = new PrintStream(myFile);
            _model.write(ps_Writer, "TTL").toString();

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {

        }
ontModel.read(_path);
```

It is important to remember that you have to specify an `OntModelSpec` when you create the OntModel (in my case use `OWL_MEM`) and make sure you use the same spec when you save your OntModel to Fuseki.  It takes me a while to find out that when you use `DatasetAccessor.putModel` to put the OntModel into Fuseki, it will convert it into a normal rdf `Model` , and if you don't specific the OntModelSpec, it will apply some reasonings when convert, and you will find out the result in Fuseki is not quite the same.